# Question not accepting edit

Tags: support, editing

I am new to Audio Video Production Beta. After having posted my first question , I found something I wanted to change and thus went into edit mode. I added 6 characters to the first sentence, then clicked save edits. Yet my question when re-posted, had in fact deleted the whole first sentence I had tried to change. Not daunted, I went back and added the whole first sentence again. Again the same thing happened.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: I've had a quick look at the edit log of your question on AVP. It seems that you only edited the tags. Could you share the sentance that you wanted to prepend?

Comment: @PelletenCate: I think that it does have something to do with what I was trying to edit. Namely that my first sentence contained the word "Hello". Some people don't seem to like greetings in questions.

Comment: That was exactly what I was thinking. We at SE have the common rule not to greet and regard. I wasn't aware though of any automated mechanism that took these out. Are you sure there wasn't some notification when your edits were "rejected"?

Comment: Well, I tried it again and it took it out, with no message. I edited with a different sentence and it left it in. Thanks for you help @PelletenCate.

Comment: Yes, common greetings are automatically removed; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/115866. /cc @PelletenCate